# why is my dropdown menu stuck? html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

This is the html code. I used images as the dropdown instead of buttons or text.

```css
/* Dropdown Button / .dropbtn { background-image: url(Images/Buttons/Resources3.png); width: 110px; height: 40px; } / The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content*/

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}


/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 110px;
  z-index: 1;
  color: black;
  padding: 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}


/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-image: url(Images/Buttons/Resources3R.png);
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <img class="dropbtn">
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <img src="../Images/Buttons/Aboutus1.png" width="110px" height="40px">
    <img src="../Images/Buttons/Aboutus2.png" width="110px" height="40px">
    <img src="../Images/Buttons/Aboutus3.png" width="110px" height="40px">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I clicked the `<>` button in the editor for you and pasted the css into relevant panels. Please delete your comments and never use comments for code updates

Comment: You can get images from https://placeholder.com/

Comment: What do you mean stuck? Your code doesnt actually do anything but display a bunch of non-existant images...

Comment: the images are saved in my folders. in stead of the drop down appearing when the mouse is hovering over it, the drop down is continuously there. Please can you show me how to create the correct code, using images for the drop down instead of buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had some errors in your code. For one thing, you were trying to hover over the unclosed div that contains the menu. For another, you set 'display: block' on the initial css!
This works:

```css
.dropbtn { background-image: url(http://via.placeholder.com/350x150); width: 110px; height: 40px; } 

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 110px;
  z-index: 1;
  color: black;
  padding: 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-image: url("http://via.placeholder.com/350x150");
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <div id="button">
 <img class="dropbtn">
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" width="40px" height="40px">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" width="90px" height="40px">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" width="110px" height="40px">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This was very helpful!

Comment: Pleasure! Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `display: block;` in `.dropdown-content { ... }` and maybe change the tag of `dropbtn` to `div` or smth. similar with a fixed width/height, like here: https://jsfiddle.net/9m3af4od/

Comment: Thanks for the help